# Cows and Bulls Game - C++

Tags: c++

Question - Implement a guessing game called Cows and Bulls. Cows represents the amount of correct guesses. Bulls represent the amount of correct guesses in the right position. For instance, the computer has 1234 and the user guesses 2135 the result being: 1 Bull and 3 Cows.

I have written the code but I keep getting 0 Bulls and 0 Cows. I have played about with it for over an hour and still cannot seem to find the problem. This version was done with characters instead of numbers but the same rules apply.

```
#include "std_lib.h";

vector<char> letters;
vector<char> answers;

void defineletters() {

  letters.push_back('a');
  letters.push_back('b');
  letters.push_back('c');
  letters.push_back('d');
}

int testcows(char a) {

  int manycows = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i) {
    if (a == letters[i]) {
      ++manycows;
    }
  }

  return manycows;
}

int testposition() {

  int manybulls = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < letters.size(); ++i) {
    if (answers[i] == letters[i]) {
      ++manybulls;
    }
  }

  return manybulls;
}

int main() {

  int cows = 0;

  char answer1;
  char answer2;
  char answer3;
  char answer4;

  cin >> answer1 >> answer2 >> answer3 >> answer4;
  answers.push_back(answer1);
  answers.push_back(answer2);
  answers.push_back(answer3);
  answers.push_back(answer4);

  cows = testcows(answer1) + testcows(answer2) + testcows(answer3) +
         testcows(answer4);

  cout << testposition() << "Bulls\n" << cows - testposition()
       << "Cows\n";

  keep_window_open("-");
}
```

Comment: maybe you should try to fix the code before you play with it for hours. Seems to be rather boring in this state.

Comment: try adding some extra output to your code (debug statements) so you can see what is happening with your code.

Comment: ... or even better start up a debugger and step through your program line by line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

defineletters is never called -> letters are uninitialized

Answer (score 1):

The `defineletters()` is never called, so the vector is never initialized, therefore have length zero.

Comment: aw wow, i knew it'd be something rediculously simple haha. thank you!